# NSURLConnection - how much LEFT to download

Tags: nsurlconnection, loading, download

I am downloading video files over wifi through my application to the iphone.

I want to make a % downloaded display (eg: loading bar style).

I thought about using `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;` but I would need to know how much data there was overall to download.

Is there any way to make a "download status" bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get expected contents length in `didRecieveResponse` delegate method (using  `expectedContentLength` in `NSURLResponse`)

then in `-didReceiveData` you get the length of data already downloaded and calculate progress percentage from it.